# It is not inserting these numbers correctly in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application where it adds questions into question rows. I have a problem though when it comes to INSERTING VALUES in the database.

I my application if I add 2 questions then it looks like this below:

```
SessionId   QuestionId   QuestionContent

ABV         1            What is 2+2?
ABV         2            What is 3+3?
```

But if I add these values in the database, then it inserts it like this:

```
 SessionId   QuestionId   QuestionContent

    ABV         3            What is 2+2?
    ABV         3            What is 3+3?
```

The problem is that it is INSERTING the next question number after those that have been added, in this case the number '3'.  How can I add the correct question numbers like the first example in the database?

Below is the INSERT VALUES code I currently have:

```
     $insertquestion = array();

foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question)
{
    $insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . "' , ' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['num_questions'] ) . "', ' ".  mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) . "'";
}

  $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";



echo($questionsql);
```

Below is the javascript code which adds the question numbers in the table rows in the application ( I have not included appending the sessionId and Questions in the code below)

```
<script>

    function insertQuestion(form) {   

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
        var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
        var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");

        $tr.append($qid);
            $tbody.append($tr); 

        ++qnum;
        $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
        $("#num_questions").val(qnum);

</script>


<form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" id ="num_questions" value="" name="num_questions">
<div id="detailsBlock">
    <table id="question">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Question Number <span id="questionNum">1</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What queries come out of `echo($questionsql);`?

Comment: @CodeCaster the query coming out $questionsql is this if I try to add 2 questions in the database: `INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) VALUES (' ABV' , ' 3', ' What is 2+2?'), (' ABV' , ' 3', ' What is 3+3?')`

Comment: @user1304948 as you see the query inserts both ID's as 3, because you insert `$_POST['num_questions']` into the ID column.

Answer (score -1):

If you just use `DELETE * FROM tableName` or `EMPTY function in phpMyAdmin` (which do `DELETE * FROM tableName`) it's normal, u just have index with `auto_increment` and when you delete all record in your table last `auto_increment_id` is keeped.

If you `TRUNCATE` this table `auto_increment_id` will be returned to 1.